# What is the natural way of using Dataset to get a FittedModel?

Tags: fitting, dataset

The new Dataset in Mathematica 10 is a great addition to the language, potentially reducing the convenience gap with R. Given this, I would like to understand what the equivalent simple or natural workflow in Mathematica is for a model fit.

In R, one can set up a data frame by columns (`c` creates a vector):

```
dataset=data.frame(days=c(1,2,6,8),area=c(3,6,8,2),frequency=c(1,4,4,2),height=c(2,3,11,6))
```

which is displayed like this:

```
  days area frequency height
1    1    3         1      2
2    2    6         4      3
3    6    8         4     11
4    8    2         2      6
```

You can then fit a model using a model formula:

```
fit=lm(height~days+area,data=dataset)
```

You could view the coefficients, for example, with `coef(fit)`

```
(Intercept)        days        area 
 -2.8167116   0.9198113   0.9278976
```

In Mathematica one option that occurs to me is:

```
dataset = Dataset[MapThread[Association, Thread /@ {"days" -> {1, 2, 6, 8},
 "area" -> {3, 6, 8, 2}, "frequency" -> {1, 4, 4, 2}, "height" -> {2, 3, 11, 6}}]]
LinearModelFit[dataset[[All, {"days", "area", "height"}]] // Normal // Values,
 {days, area}, {days, area}]
```

The specific questions are:

1. What is a more natural way to create the Dataset in Mathematica? I find it helpful to have the data specified by columns and for the column name to be near the data, but if that idiom is not natural in Mathematica, that would be good to know.
2. Is there a simpler way to do the fit, perhaps one as straightforward as the R approach? Specifying the column names is important for experimentation and model selection when the number of potential variables is large.

Given some comments below, here are some clarifications:

- In R the data frame is a core structure and it is manipulated in many ways e.g. by combining data frames, adding new columns, modifying existing columns etc. My underlying interest is to understand to what extent Dataset can play this role. I think the column view is pretty important for this.
- Functional wrappers can be written to suit an individual's way of doing things. However, I am interested to know if there is any fundamental or natural way of approaching this in Mathematica. There is clearly a natural way to do it in R.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Inspired by WReach's answer, I started playing with `Query` based approach and here's what I came up with:

```
data = {"days" -> {1, 2, 6, 8}, "area" -> {3, 6, 8, 2}, 
         "frequency" -> {1, 4, 4, 2}, "height" -> {2, 3, 11, 6}}
```

With the data in the above form, we just create a `Dataset` simply as follows:

```
dataset = Dataset[data];
```

Don't worry that it does not look how you want yet, it gets better.

We can transform that `Dataset` into what you want as follows (the cool part):

```
(* note the v10 operator syntax and RightComposition form *)
dataset[Map[Thread] /* Transpose /* Map[Association]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Cool huh?

The fitting part remains the same as in my previous answer (see that for a different approach), so let's lump `em all:

```
var = {days, area};

dataset[Map[Thread] /* Transpose /* Map[Association]]
                         [LinearModelFit[#, var, var] &, {#days, #area, #height} &]
```

Actually, if your data will be in this form in most cases then you can store the transformation operation as a symbols `OwnValues`:

```
toDataset = Map[Thread] /* Transpose /* Map[Association];
```

Now, even cleaner:

```
dataset[toDataset][LinearModelFit[#, var, var] &, {#days, #area, #height} &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So fresh and so clean.

Comment: This is indeed fresh and interesting, but as WReach said in introducing the idea, not particularly natural (nor elegant in my opinion). Still, it makes one think.

Comment: I think what I’m missing is a way to express the relationship between the independent and dependent variables symbolically and for LinearModelFit to make use of the Dataset appropriately and parsimoniously. Although I might get used to it, I also found it somewhat jarring to pass a function to the Dataset when the end result is not a Dataset. Nevertheless, I think enough time has passed to conclude that this is a natural approach for Mathematica at present, so I accept.

Answer (score 19):

I was playing around, trying to come up with a purely query-based solution.  The result is by no means natural, but perhaps it holds some academic interest or will spark some insight into a better answer:

```
Dataset[
  { "days" -> {1, 2, 6, 8}
  , "area" -> {3, 6, 8, 2}
  , "frequency" -> {1, 4, 4, 2}
  , "height" -> {2, 3, 11, 6}
  }
][ Transpose, Thread
][ All, Association
][ LinearModelFit[#, {days, area}, {days, area}]&, {#days, #area, #height}&
]
```

[image: fitted model screenshot]

Comment: Definitely an interesting approach. By the way you don't need the quotations in the named pure functions since the keys are strings. +1

Comment: @RunnyKine Indeed ;) Leftovers from one of the other 50 variations I tried, no doubt.  Removed.

Comment: I understand, I tried about as many :)

Comment: Thanks, that is surprisingly clean! Clearly `LinearModelFit` should get smarter about dealing with `Dataset` (as should `Classify` and `Predict`, etc).

Answer (score 14):

For your first question assuming you have the data in the following arrangement:

```
data = {{1, 2, 6, 8}, {3, 6, 8, 2}, {1, 4, 4, 2}, {2, 3, 11, 6}}
header = {"days", "area", "frequency", "height"}
```

You can create the `Dataset` as follows:

```
dataset = Dataset @ Map[AssociationThread[header, #] &] @ Transpose[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

While I think the above method is most natural, if you still insist on having the data arranged the `R` way, you can still do the pre-processing once and use the above approach:

```
rdata = {"days" -> {1, 2, 6, 8}, "area" -> {3, 6, 8, 2}, 
         "frequency" -> {1, 4, 4, 2}, "height" -> {2, 3, 11, 6}}
```

Pre-process:

```
{header, data} = Transpose[rdata /. Rule -> List]
```

> ```
>  {{"days", "area", "frequency", "height"},
>  {{1, 2, 6, 8}, {3, 6, 8, 2}, {1, 4, 4, 2}, {2, 3, 11, 6}}}
> ```

Then proceed as above.
Now, to `Query` the data for the fit just do:

```
dataset[LinearModelFit[#, {days, area}, {days, area}] &, {#days, #area, #height} &]
```

Or if we set `var = {days, area}`, then:

```
dataset[LinearModelFit[#, var, var] &, {#days, #area, #height} &]
```

OR

```
Query[LinearModelFit[#, var, var] &, {#days, #area, #height} &]@dataset
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you. This creates the Dataset, but in the definition the column data are still separated from their corresponding names (e.g. `height` is not obviously linked to `{2,3,11,6}`, which is how I tend to see things in R.

Comment: `Normal @ dataset[All, "height"]` gives the list, where `dataset` is the Dataset in the above answer.

Comment: @YiWang my question is about the definition and not how to query the Dataset.

Comment: @RunnyKine using the `rdata` you defined, the approach given in my question (edited) would be: `Dataset[MapThread[Association, Thread /@ rdata]]` which seems simpler than what you propose.

Comment: @Simplex, it looks simpler because I've used the operator form of `/@` here and because the name `AssociationThread` is long. But I assure you, it's faster.

Comment: @Simplex. See my update for the fit.

Comment: @RunnyKine, performance is important for many, but for the amount of data I'm using (<100000 rows), the difference is negligible. Clarity of expression is far more important for my purposes. Nevertheless, I realise this is a matter of opinion, so thank you for sharing yours.

Comment: @Simplex. I understand, see my second answer below.

Comment: @Simplex, to be fair, to get the data in the form of `rdata` in *Mathematica* will require some processing anyways, so my original form, I think, is the most natural. Since you can just read a heading from a data file as the first row, then get the rest of the data. But, like you said, it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 5):

If your data is most conveniently expressed as in the form

```
{key_1 -> (val_11, val_12, ..., val_1n}, ..., key_m -> (val_m1, val_m2, ..., val_mn},}
```

then it would be a good idea to define a function to create datasets directly form such data, which can be done as follows:

```
rulesToDataset[data : {Rule[_, {__}] ..}] :=
  Dataset[Association /@ Inner[Rule, Sequence @@ Transpose[List @@@ data], List]]
```

Example:

```
data = 
  {"days" -> {1, 2, 6, 8}, "area" -> {3, 6, 8, 2}, 
   "frequency" -> {1, 4, 4, 2}, "height" -> {2, 3, 11, 6}};
rulesToDataset[data]
```

[image: dataset]

Comment: I can see the value of defining a function if there isn't an obvious straightforward way of doing it directly. I gather there might not be, which is what I was interested to know.